# I have a javascript that stops working when a button is not showed. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, reference, show-hide, referenceerror

I've got 4 buttons and each button opens a section and closes the other. There is a possibility that one or the buttons are stay hidden because of a switch in the backend which you can toggle to make it visible (or to hide).

Now, if one or more buttons are not visible the script stops working. If I toggle all the buttons on, the buttons display and the script is working.

I have this code and it works fine (as long as all the buttons are visible):

```
<style> 
.elementor-editor-active .hidden { 
    display:block; 
} 
.hidden{ 
    display:none; 
} 
.shown{ 
    display: block !important; 
} 

.btn_active_state{
background-color: #FFCC00 !important;
}
.btn_active_state a{
font-weight: bold !important;
}

</style>

<script>
var divs
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4");

    btn1.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("sect1",this);
    };

    btn2.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("sect2",this);
    };
    

    btn3.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("sect3",this);
    };

    btn4.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("sect4",this);
    };

function toggleDivs(s,btn){
if(btn.classList.contains("btn_active_state")){
document.getElementById(s).classList.remove("shown");
btn.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
document.getElementById(s).classList.remove("shown");
return;
}else{
btn1.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
btn2.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
btn3.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
btn4.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
btn.classList.add("btn_active_state");
document.getElementById("sect1").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect2").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect3").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect4").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById(s).classList.add("shown","fade");
}
}
//force button1 state initialise, if required
//btn1.focus();
//btn1.click();



</script>
```

The script stops working when I toggle one or more buttons to OFF (so they don't display on the front-end). I saw solutions with a Try Catch method, but I don't know (if this is the right way to fix it), where to implement it...

**I am using Elementor in Wordpress to accomplish this.** (HTML widget where I pasted this code and named the sections and buttons to the names named in the code).

Side note: I'm not an expert in Javascript.

Thanks advance!

Comment: please add all your code revelant to the problem, including the HTML [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I would suggest that you try to simplify your code. try to use only 2 buttons for now, rather than 4.  Get that working properly first. I think you would want to be able to run a function( show this area ) and make that work correctly. then you can add additional buttons / sections.  A 'behind the curtain' way of looking at your code: embrace lists... like objects, and arrays. your items of interest should be in one list and your functions should process that list

Comment: This piece of code works just fine, but as long all the buttons are visible. It stops on one or more buttons when they're not visible anymore (switched off). By the way this is all the code I have...Simplifying and starting with 2 buttons will also not work if I toggle an of the switches in the backend OFF.

Comment: there is a lot of duplication and repetition here, I can appreciate that you are not a js adept, but you are on your way. you should read into DRY ( don't repeat yourself ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I had 4 Elementor widgets (I used this as buttons) with every widget a unique ID (#btn1, #btn2, #btn3 & #btn4). I had also 4 different Elementor sections with their own ID (#sect1, #sect2, #sect3 & #sect4). If you clicked one of the button, the respective section would display (btn1 shows sect1, btn2 shows sect2 etc..).

The standard script (posted in first place) worked fined when all the buttons (btn1, btn2 etc.) where visible (not rendered, not in the code) on the page. This is because I used the Dynamic Visibility options in the 'Advanced' tab in Elementor (Crocoblock JetEngine/Elementor Pro).

The problem arose when 1 or more buttons were missing because of the Dynamic Visibility (If a switch in the CPT turned off, it will not show the widget). The script stopped working and none of the buttons worked again.

Now, I used this code in a HTML widget and placed the HTML widget under the sections (above the sections are the widgets acting like buttons). The first part of the script gives an 'active' state to the button you click on. Assure that you set the class of the button you want to have an active state as default, to 'active':

```html
<style> 
.elementor-editor-active .hidden { 
    display:block; 
} 
.hidden{ 
    display:none; 
} 
.shown{ 
    display: block !important; 
} 

#btn1, #btn2, #btn3, #btn4 {
    cursor: pointer;
}


.active h2  {
font-weight: bold !important;
}



</style>

<script>
var activeButton = document.getElementById("btn1");

function toggleActive(btn) {
  if (activeButton && activeButton != btn) {
    activeButton.classList.remove("active");
  }
  activeButton = btn;
  btn.classList.add("active");
}

var sect1 = document.getElementById("sect1");
var sect2 = document.getElementById("sect2");
var sect3 = document.getElementById("sect3");
var sect4 = document.getElementById("sect4");

try {
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.onclick = function(event){
    toggleActive(btn1);
    document.getElementById("sect1").classList.add("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect2").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect3").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect4").classList.remove("shown");
};
} catch (error) {
  console.log("btn1 not found on the page. Error: " + error);
}
try {
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
btn2.onclick = function(event){
    toggleActive(btn2);
    document.getElementById("sect1").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect2").classList.add("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect3").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect4").classList.remove("shown");
};
} catch (error) {
  console.log("btn1 not found on the page. Error: " + error);
}
try {
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
btn3.onclick = function(event){
    toggleActive(btn3);
    document.getElementById("sect1").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect2").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect3").classList.add("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect4").classList.remove("shown");
};
} catch (error) {
  console.log("btn1 not found on the page. Error: " + error);
}
try {
var btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4");
btn4.onclick = function(event){
    toggleActive(btn4);
    document.getElementById("sect1").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect2").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect3").classList.remove("shown");
    document.getElementById("sect4").classList.add("shown");
};
} catch (error) {
  console.log("btn1 not found on the page. Error: " + error);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have finished this up. you can extend it easily by adding to the buttons list ( at the top of the document ).  This is a system to create the buttons, action and sections. It allows you to toggle between them, essentially like tabs.  It is likely not the best implementation, but it is a working system, something to get started with.  It separates the views from the buttons, two functions to control the state of each. one is controlling the buttons, the other the views. this should be your approach moving forward... Keep It Stupid Simple.  Avoid complexity, embrace readability. if you want code to be ultra compact and "efficient", use webpack :D

```js
//define buttons
const buttons = [ 
    { id:'btn1',
      section:'sect1',
      label:'Button 1'},
    { id:'btn2',
      section:'sect2',
      label:'Button 2'},
    { id:'btn3',
      section:'sect3',
      label:'Button 3'},
    { id:'btn4',
      section:'sect4',
      label:'Button 4'}
      ];
//console.table(buttons);
const views = [];
// create buttons and assign click, create sections
for ( const button of buttons){
  let nB = document.createElement('button');
  nB.id=button.id;
  nB.innerText=button.label;
  nB.onclick=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleView( button.section, views );
    toggleButton( button.id, buttons );
  }
  document.getElementById('menu').appendChild(nB);
  // create the span / divs
  let nD = document.createElement('div');
  nD.id=button.section;
  // put something in here for testing
  nD.innerText=button.section;
  nD.classList.add('hidden');
  views.push(button.section);
  document.getElementById('viewer').appendChild(nD);
}

// function to change sections
function toggleView( view, viewList ){
  //console.log( view );
  //console.log( viewList );
  // hide all
  for ( const v of viewList ){
    // not actually the elements, but just reference
    document.getElementById( v ).classList.remove('shown');
    // unhide 'view' by id
    if ( v == view ) {
      //console.log(`view ${v} found`);
      document.getElementById( v ).classList.add('shown');
    }
  }
}

function toggleButton( button, buttonList ){
  // console.log(button);
  // console.log(buttonList);
  // enable all
  // disable this button id
  // iterate through managed list
  for ( const b of buttonList ){
    // console.log(b);
    document.getElementById(b.id).classList.add('btn_active_state');
    if ( b.id == button ) document.getElementById(b.id).classList.remove('btn_active_state');
  }
}
toggleButton( buttons[0], buttons );
```

```css
.elementor-editor-active .hidden { 
    display:block; 
} 
.hidden{ 
    display:none; 
} 
.shown{ 
    display: block !important; 
} 

.btn_active_state{
background-color: #FFCC00 !important;
}
.btn_active_state a{
font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id='menu'></div>
<div id='viewer'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, thanks, but as I said, my Javascript is not that good to finish this. Hopefully somebody has another idea or addition. Thanks for your effort, appreciate it!

Comment: @DaandeWilt I've updated this to be working as I've intended. it works the way which you would like. I would recommend that you review this code and try to learn from it. I'm not a perfect JS developer, but I have had to maintain code for about a decade.... readability is number one thing to consider, also everything is a list so think like that, efficiency in any capacity should be the last thing on your mind.

Comment: Thanks, but I think we are misunderstanding each other. Maybe I can make it more clear with the screenshot below. If I click a widget (Elementor widget with ID) a section (containers with ID) shows or hide: https://prnt.sc/Rj62wNMIcXGc

The Elementor widgets with an ID show/hide based on toggling a switch: https://prnt.sc/ZEDjI5FFT-2I

Now what I've said earlier, and now I'm gonna repeat myself again ( ;-) ): The piece of code worked fine, but if a button is not visible, the functionality is gone. I can click as hard as I can on the buttons, but it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: And for your information; I am just a branding specialist trying my best to understand and learn from everything I can. And so I am trying to understand Javascript bit by bit by trial and error.. I appreciate your effort and time checking this out for me!!

Comment: Daan, that's great that you are getting your hands dirty with this, great effort! I'm a life long learner too. I find that my best quality is simply persistence; I keep failing until I succeed :) There will always be room for improvement in most things, it all comes down to support of the solution.  I suggested this 'major' change because it is easier to read and easier to extend, because it is a system, rather than a bunch of static code with repetition. But, I think I see now the main issue with your code and I will post another answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? I've replaced 'this' with the btn var itself when calling toggleDivs(). So rather than toggleDivs("sect1", this) use toggleDivs("sect1", btn1)

```js
    btn1.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("sect1",btn1);
    };

    btn2.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("sect2",btn2);
    };
    

    btn3.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("sect3",btn3);
    };

    btn4.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("sect4",btn4);
    };
```

```js
// try to assign the var btn1 to the element
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
// check to see if it is valid / not null
if ( btn1 ){
  // if it gets here, then the button is valid
  btn1.onclick = (e) =>{
    // show / hide sections
  }
}
//otherwise, if btn1==null it will continue to the next
```

Comment: Hey thanks man! I changed all of them, but didn't work unfortunately. Text element "btn3" was hidden (turned of by the switch, so not visible) and the other buttons stopped working. Can it be something like this?: 

try {
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
} catch(error) {
console.log("Element not found, but script continues");
}

I also found this (the IF statement with the exclamation mark in combination with" || undefined" behind the variable)- https://prnt.sc/XCTewH9SgscT

Now I get only this error (again, buttons stopped working) - https://prnt.sc/gPAjIzmjeFOW

Comment: Looking at your errors, it would indicate that your assignment is not happening. try console.log(btn1); console.log(btn2); etc. within your section with "One or more buttons are not defined".  I wonder if the button element is being removed completely by something, rather than just having it set as invisible by CSS.  Essentially, if you are getting the error, which button is not existing at that time

Comment: Also, within the browser, you can inspect the elements on the page, a quick way to do this is right click on the thing on the page and select "inspect" or "inspect element"

Comment: btn3 is completely gone! > https://prnt.sc/Vd21daXIPVp1
These are the errors in the console > https://prnt.sc/AEZaGcnTTPu0
..and this is what you see if I click on the error > https://prnt.sc/TGIl7Tw8eeCg

Comment: OK, well, that's not what you were hoping for. the element is either not there in the first place or it is being removed for some reason.  Can you figure out when that happens? when the button is removed?

Comment: No, unfortunately haha. The text-element is removed by Dynamic Visibility Options in Elementor. If a switch toggles off in Edit post screen, the text-element is not shown on the front-end > https://prnt.sc/e5Lzgu3yjSTW

Comment: OK. I'm not familiar with Elementor, maybe it can be configured to just change the CSS, rather than remove the element? but, working with that, you could change your code to try and rescan and get the available elements first.  does the page refresh when the button is toggled?  I think your code to scan for buttons, should be attached to all of these sliders. basically, when the slider is toggled, it should update the vars btn1, btn2, etc. another way would be to remove any button changes - changing the css for the button on the click

Comment: No, unfortunately he always removes the element. But I checked it again, made some changes in the code and now I'm one step further! This code: https://prnt.sc/jNEzDP46X32G will not stop the script, even if btn3 is not on the page! So far so good, but now btn4 (payoff - https://prnt.sc/KM5cOlGCMzT_) doesn't work. The first 2 (basislogo &  logo variaties) do work!! The console gave me this error: https://prnt.sc/g0bucAPqytxw I think the btn('s) after the one that is not visible on the page, will not work. Looks like the browser stops reading the rest of the script..

Comment: That's good work, you're making progress. this is worth checking out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ .

Comment: Finally! Everything works. I will thank you for your patience, time and knowledge @This-guy! Much, much appreciated! Hallelujaa! This is the final code: https://prnt.sc/tApO5w92zjiS

Comment: Excellent! Great job, you put in the effort and got the result you wanted.  I'm glad that I could help you out.  I will still suggest that you take a look back at this code every now and again and try to make some improvements.  But the important thing is that it functions.  You can now start making some improvements to the code. things like making a function to replace all of the static code. keep reading about DRY principles and thinking in a functional / list processing way and apply that to your code :) Keep reading, keep learning :)

Comment: Also, you can post an answer to your own question ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll keep it in mind! :-)